# Direct3D c++ api how to update vertex buffer?

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, direct3d, directx-11

So how can one update values in vertex buffer bound into device object using `IASetVertexBuffers` method? Also will changing values in this buffer before call to `Draw()` and `Present()`? Also will the image be updated according to these new values in buffer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To update a vertex buffer by the CPU, you must first create a dynamic vertex buffer that allows the CPU to write to it.  To do this, call `ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer`with `Usage` set to `D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC` and `CPUAccessFlags` set to `D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE`. Example:

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC desc;
ZeroMemory( &desc, sizeof( desc ) );
desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
desc.ByteWidth = size;
desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
d3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &desc, initialVertexData, &vertexBuffer );
```

Now that you have a dynamic vertex buffer, you can update it using [ID3D11DeviceContext::Map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476457(v=vs.85).aspx) and [ID3D11DeviceContext::Unmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476485(v=vs.85).aspx). Example:

```
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE resource;
d3dDeviceContext->Map( vertexBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &resource );
memcpy( resource.pData, sourceData, vertexDataSize );
d3dDeviceContext->Unmap( vertexBuffer, 0 );
```

where sourceData is the new vertex data you want to put into the buffer.

This is one method for updating a vertex buffer where you are uploading a whole new set of vertex data and discarding previous contents. There are also other ways to update a vertex buffer. For example, you could leave the current contents and only modify certain values, or you could update only certain regions of the vertex buffer instead of the whole thing.

Each method will have its own usage and performance characteristics. It all depends on what your data is and how you intend on using it. [This NVIDIA presentation](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/gamedev/files/gdc12/Efficient_Buffer_Management_McDonald.pdf) gives some advice on the best way to update your buffers for different usages.

Yes, you will want to call this and `IASetVertexBuffers` before `Draw()` and `Present()` to see the updated results for the current frame. You don't necessarily need to update the vertex buffer contents before calling `IASetVertexBuffers`. Those can be in either order.

Comment: Is this a wrong way to animate stuff because when I tried this, my triangles corner moves around appropriately, but it blinks during this animation.

Comment: It may or may not be the most efficient way to update the buffer based on your data, but it should work just fine for now. Your flickering might be because you aren't double buffering during rendering. I saw you created another question, so we can address it over there.

Comment: Ideally you don't animate through modifying the geometry as this is inefficient. Ideally you use static IBs/VBs and then apply movement and animation through transformations and programmable shaders. There are cases where dynamic geometry submission makes sense (usually terrain and portal systems), in which case you should look at the ``PrimitiveBatch`` class in [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929).