# Rendering with Directx10

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, directx-11, directx-10

During the run-time I expect that all objects that was successfully created and drawn in the program during the initialization to change their positions per each call of GraphicsClass::Render() function. But nothing happens: all figures (points in my case) stand still, and there is no any movement.

I know that common approach in Directx10 is usage of world, view and projection matrices. But here I directly change the buffer which is then sent to ID3D10Device object to draw, because I need draw many objects with their distinct trajectories, and each object is represented by a point.

I suspect that error could be in the method ColorShaderClass::SetShaderParameters. So, I've only attached the code which are directly connected with rendering in the program.

**graphicsclass.h**

```
class GraphicsClass
{
public:
    GraphicsClass();
    GraphicsClass(const GraphicsClass&);
    ~GraphicsClass();

    bool Initialize(int, int, HWND);
    void Shutdown();
    bool Frame(double time);

private:
    bool Render(double time);

private:
    D3DClass * m_Direct3D;
    CameraClass* m_Camera;
    ModelClass* m_Model;
    ColorShaderClass* m_ColorShader;

    //amount of bodies
    int m_bodies;
};
```

**graphicsclass.cpp**

```
bool GraphicsClass::Render()
{
    // Clear the buffers to begin the scene.
    m_Direct3D->BeginScene(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);

    bool result;

    // Clear the buffers to begin the scene.
    m_Direct3D->BeginScene(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    // Generate the view matrix based on the camera's position.
    m_Camera->Render();

    // Put the model vertex and index buffers on the graphics pipeline to prepare them for drawing.
    m_Model->Render(m_Direct3D->GetDevice());

    // Render the model using the color shader.
    result = m_ColorShader->Render(m_Direct3D->GetDevice(), m_Model->GetIndexCount(),m_Model->GetPositions());
    if (!result)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Present the rendered scene to the screen.
    m_Direct3D->EndScene();
    return true;
}
```

**modelclsss.h**

```
class ModelClass
{
private:
    struct ModelVertex {
        XMFLOAT4 Pos;
    };

public:
    ModelClass(int); //pass number of bodies
    ModelClass(const ModelClass&);
    ~ModelClass();

    bool Initialize(ID3D10Device*);
    void Shutdown();
    void Render(ID3D10Device*);

    int GetIndexCount();
    float * GetPositions();

private:
    bool InitializeBuffers(ID3D10Device*);
    void ShutdownBuffers();
    void RenderBuffers(ID3D10Device*);

private:
    ID3D10Buffer *m_vertexBuffer, *m_indexBuffer;
    int m_vertexCount, m_indexCount;

    float  * m_positions;
    float  * m_velocities;
    NBodySystemGPU * m_bodySystem;
    int m_bodies;
};
```

**modelclass.cpp**

```
void ModelClass::Render(ID3D10Device* device)
{
    //update bodies' positions
    bool result;
    //m_bodySystem->update(0.00001f, m_positions, m_velocities, result);
    for (int i = 0; i < m_bodies; ++i) {
        m_positions[i] += 0.5;
    }
    InitializeBuffers(device);
    // Put the vertex and index buffers on the graphics pipeline to prepare them for drawing.
    RenderBuffers(device);
    return;
}

void ModelClass::RenderBuffers(ID3D10Device* device)
{
    unsigned int stride;
    unsigned int offset;

    // Set vertex buffer stride and offset.
    stride = sizeof(ModelVertex);
    offset = 0;

    // Set the vertex buffer to active in the input assembler so it can be rendered.
    device->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &m_vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);

    // Set the index buffer to active in the input assembler so it can be rendered.
    device->IASetIndexBuffer(m_indexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

    // Set the type of primitive that should be rendered from this vertex buffer, in this case triangles.
    device->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_POINTLIST);

    return;
}

bool ModelClass::InitializeBuffers(ID3D10Device* device)
{
    unsigned long* indices;
    D3D10_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDesc, indexBufferDesc;
    D3D10_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertexData, indexData;
    HRESULT result;

    // Create the index array.
    indices = new unsigned long[m_bodies];
    if(!indices)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Load the vertex array with data.
    for (int i = 0; i < m_bodies; ++i) {
        indices[i] = i;
    }

    // Set up the description of the vertex buffer.
    ZeroMemory(&vertexBufferDesc, sizeof(vertexBufferDesc));
    vertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    vertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(ModelVertex) * m_bodies;
    vertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vertexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D10_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    vertexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    // Give the subresource structure a pointer to the vertex data.
    ZeroMemory(&vertexData, sizeof(vertexData));
    vertexData.pSysMem = m_positions;
    vertexData.SysMemPitch = 0;
    vertexData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

    // Now finally create the vertex buffer.
    result = device->CreateBuffer(&vertexBufferDesc, &vertexData, &m_vertexBuffer);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Set up the description of the index buffer.
    ZeroMemory(&indexBufferDesc, sizeof(indexBufferDesc));
    indexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    indexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(unsigned long) * m_bodies;
    indexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    indexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D10_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    indexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    // Give the subresource structure a pointer to the index data.
    indexData.pSysMem = indices;

    // Create the index buffer.
    result = device->CreateBuffer(&indexBufferDesc, &indexData, &m_indexBuffer);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Release the arrays now that the vertex and index buffers have been created and loaded.

    delete [] indices;
    indices = 0;

    return true;
}
```

**colorshadersclss.h**

```
class ColorShaderClass
{
private:
    struct ColorVertex {
        XMFLOAT4 Pos;
    };

public:
    ColorShaderClass(int); //pass number of bodies
    ColorShaderClass(const ColorShaderClass&);
    ~ColorShaderClass();

    bool Initialize(ID3D10Device*, HWND);
    void Shutdown();
    bool Render(ID3D10Device*, int,float *);

private:
    bool InitializeShader(ID3D10Device*, HWND, WCHAR*, WCHAR*);
    void ShutdownShader();
    void OutputShaderErrorMessage(ID3D10Blob*, HWND, WCHAR*);

    bool SetShaderParameters(ID3D10Device*,float *);
    void RenderShader(ID3D10Device*, int);

private:
    ID3D10VertexShader* m_vertexShader;
    ID3D10PixelShader* m_pixelShader;
    ID3D10InputLayout* m_layout;
    ID3D10Buffer* m_matrixBuffer;

    //Body system 
    int m_bodies;
};
```

**colorshaders.cpp**

```
bool ColorShaderClass::Render(ID3D10Device* device, int indexCount, float * positions)
{
    bool result;

    // Set the shader parameters that it will use for rendering.
    result = SetShaderParameters(device,positions);
    if (!result)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Now render the prepared buffers with the shader.
    RenderShader(device, indexCount);

    return true;
}

bool ColorShaderClass::SetShaderParameters(ID3D10Device* device, float * positions)
{
    HRESULT result;
    void* mappedResource;

    unsigned int bufferNumber;

    // Lock the constant buffer so it can be written to.
    result = m_matrixBuffer->Map(D3D10_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Get a pointer to the data in the constant buffer.
    memcpy(mappedResource, positions, 4 * m_bodies * sizeof(float));

    // Unlock the constant buffer.
    m_matrixBuffer->Unmap();

    // Set the position of the constant buffer in the vertex shader.
    bufferNumber = 0;

    // Finally set the constant buffer in the vertex shader with the updated values.
    device->VSSetConstantBuffers(bufferNumber, 1, &m_matrixBuffer);

    return true;
}

void ColorShaderClass::RenderShader(ID3D10Device* device, int indexCount)
{
    // Set the vertex input layout.
    device->IASetInputLayout(m_layout);

    // Set the vertex and pixel shaders that will be used to render the objects.
    device->VSSetShader(m_vertexShader);
    device->PSSetShader(m_pixelShader);

    // Render the objects.
    device->DrawIndexed(indexCount, 0, 0);

    return;
}
```

**color.ps**

```
// Pixel Shader
float4 PS( float4 Pos : SV_POSITION ) : SV_Target
{
    return float4( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );    // White, with Alpha = 1
}
```

**color.vs**

```
// GLOBALS 
cbuffer MatrixBuffer { 
    float4 updatedPosition;
};

float4 VS( float4 Pos : POSITION ) : SV_POSITION
{
    return Pos;
}
```

Comment: It looks like your Graphics::Render class calls BeginScene twice.  I don't know if that's the source of your problem, but it seems like something you'd want to fix.

Comment: Thanks. The first call is unnecessary, of course. The problem still exists.

Comment: There's no reason at all to be using Direct3D 10. You should be using Direct3D 11 which has better [hardware support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels/), more [supporting open source utility code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/), and has more community support. See also the [DirectX Tool Kit tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started). The port from Direct3D 10 is straight-forward. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476190.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are are updating the values stores in `float * m_positions;`

You are changing the values on the CPU side. It's not the actual values stored on the gpu, the one you specified when you created `m_vertexBuffer`

To do so you need to call in the render function `Initialize(ID3D10Device*, HWND);` again

There should be a line of code which look like:

```
vertexData.pSysMem = vertices;
vertexData.SysMemPitch = 0;
vertexData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

// Now create the vertex buffer.
result = device->CreateBuffer(&vertexBufferDesc, &vertexData, &m_vertexBuffer);
```

here vertices is your m_positions + your color i suspect.

This is not recommended but should do the job.

If you want to look further you need to create this buffer with a `D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC` flag and update the value with

```
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE resource;
d3dDeviceContext->Map( vertexBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &resource );
memcpy( resource.pData, sourceData, vertexDataSize );
d3dDeviceContext->Unmap( vertexBuffer, 0 );
```

have a look to:
[Direct3D c++ api how to update vertex buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453773/direct3d-c-api-how-to-update-vertex-buffer)

I hope you find what is relevant to you.
Razterizer is awesome

Comment: The initialization was done in the same manner. The problem actually can be in m_verexBuffer updating. Now I'll try to find the way to Map() and Unmap() in Directx10 and share with the results.

Comment: The thing i wanted to point is that when you offset your vertices by 0.5, thoose new values are not the one on the gpu. You cantry to recreate the buffer in your `ModelClass::Render()` before calling RenderBuffers() call InitialiserBuffer once again.

Comment: I've modified the code in the question area with the body of the ModelClass::InitialiseBuffer function. I've added the call of InitialiseBuffer(device) inside of ModelClass::Render() and changed the way of the m_vertexBuffer creation to dynamic. It didn't help. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Sorry, i did'nt spot that it was the shader sending the new positions, it should have work since the beguining. Can we have a look to your pixel shader ?

Comment: Sure, I've attached it to the question.

Comment: I think you are indeed reading the positions from the vertexBuffer not the matrixBuffer sent by the shader.  `float4 VS( float4 Pos : POSITION )`If you want to use your matrixBuffer you might need to add it as a global variable something close to `cbuffer MatrixBuffer
{
    float4 updatedPosition
};
`

Comment: I've not caught the idea of using global variable. Do you mean to use the cbuffer MatrixBuffer { float4 updatedPosition } instead of  ID3D10Buffer* m_matrixBuffer? What is cbuffer?

Comment: When you are passing your matrixBuffer which can contain (matrice, lightColor, ...) you have to add it at the top of your hlsl file, this way you can use it in your shader code. Have a look to http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut04.html for a simple constant buffer containing the matrice. In your code the matrix are replaced by your new positions values.

Comment: Okay. I've defined the global variable. Also trying to work with m_vertexBuffer buffer. Haven't solved the problem yet

Comment: Rastertek tutorials are very useful, but they have one fundamental flaw shared with most of the DirectX 11 books: They recommend using the [legacy DirectX SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) and  the deprecated D3DX11 library. See [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/).